# Probability arrangement of numbers with repeating digits

Tags: probability, permutations

This is a two part question:

> The digits $1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5$  are arranged to form a number with no repetitions, find the probability that the number will be:
>
> a) Greater than 200,000
>
> b) Odd

For a), I understand that the probability will be the number of permutations, where a number greater than 200,000, is divided by the total arrangements which is $6!\over 3!$ due to the repetition of 3. But when calculating the permutations for $n>200,000$ there is apparently $5!\over 3!$ ways of doing so according to official answers and so there is a $5!\over 3!$÷ $6!\over 3!$=$1\over 6$ probability, but $5!\over 3!$ only accounts for the last 5 digits of $n$ because the first digit may be $3, 3, 3, 4, 5$, so there should be $5(5!)\over 3!$ ways of arranging $n>200,000$, why am I wrong?

Secondly, b) states the probability of obtaining an odd number is $1-$($5!\over 3!$÷ $6!\over 3!$)=$5\over 6$, but it seems that it is also the probability of arranging $n≤200,000$ because it is the complementary probability.
So this is an assumption that all permutations $n≤200,000$ are odd but obviously there can be $n=133354 , 133534$ and other permutations ending in four, so how is this calculation correct?

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the number is greater than $200,000$ equls to the probability that the first digit is not $1$, which is $1 - 1 / 6 = 5 / 6$.
The probability that the number is odd equals to the probability that the last digit is not $4$, which is $1 - 1 / 6 = 5 / 6$.

Comment: What you have done for part A is essentially what I have done myself, but the answer is $1/6$ so I need to understand why that is the answer. Nevertheless thank you for pointing out your calculations for part B.

Comment: Maybe you don't necessarily have to use all of the digits. Otherwise the answer 1/6 just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AndreiLenedin  The answer $1/6$ for part (a) would be correct if the number must be *less* than $200,000$.  However, Amit's answer is correct for the stated problem.